# How is the relationship antisymetric

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have $R={(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5)}$.

My book tells me that $R$ is antisymmetric. Antisymmetric is if $(x R y)$ and $(y R x)$ then $x = y$.

Shouldn't I see something like ${(1,2),(2,1)}$ or ${(1,1),(2,2)}$?

Comment: *anti*symmetric means that if $xRy$ and $yRx$, then $x=y$. However, if $xRy$ implies $\neg yRx$, which is true for your $R$, then the conjunction $xRy$ and $yRx$ is *never* true, so the conditional $xRy \land yRx \to x=y$ is *always* true.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yep just caught it too. Merci.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood the definition of "antisymmetric."

You definitely shouldn't have $(1, 2)$ *and* $(2, 1)$ in your relation, if it's antisymmetric - that would mean $1=2$! (Which, I hope, is false.)

Meanwhile, note that antisymmetry doesn't say "if and only if" - the definition does not require $(a, b)\in R$ if $a=b$. So while you may have e.g. $(1, 1)$ in your relation, there's no need to.

Looking at your specific relation, $R$: do you see any $a\not=b$ with $(a, b)$ and $(b, a)$ in $R$? If so, what are they? If not, do you see why this means $R$ is antisymmetric?

Comment: Ok, so it is true as long as there are no contradictions. There doesn't have to be any direct evidence, just that it "could" be true?

Comment: I think what you need to understand is that the definition of antisymmetric is an implication. That is, whenever one condition is met (here, (a,b) and (b,a)), then another must also be met (here, a=b). If the first condition is never met, what we have is vacuous truth; the implication must be true because the prior condition never occurs. It's like saying every purple cow has yellow spots; there are no purple cows, so there are no purple cows without yellow spots, so it is true. There are no occurrences of both (a,b) and (b,a) in your relation, so it is vacuously antisymmetric.

Comment: @WP0987 Let me phrase it as: a relation $R$ is antisymmetric iff there are **no** distinct $a, b$ with $(a, b), (b, a)\in R$.